# Google Sheets function to get closest datetime that hasn't already passed, but output blank if there are no results?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I rows with multiple dates entered across the columns. I'm trying to create a formula so that on each row, I can see the next upcoming date and sort my sheet to put the rows in order of next upcoming date, whichever column that date is in.

I have this formula which works so long as there is an upcoming date:

```
=ArrayFormula(MIN(IF(E2:Z2<TODAY(),FALSE,E2:Z2)))
```

It correctly gives me the next closest date that hasn't already passed. But if the row has no dates in it at all, or all of the dates in the row has passed, it outputs 12/30/1899.

[image]

How can I make it return empty instead of 12/30/1899 (I assume the min date value)?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTA(E2:Z2),MIN(IF(TODAY()<E2:Z2,E2:Z2)),))
```

[image]

You could also do it with a single formula in `D2`:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(BYROW(E2:Z,LAMBDA(r,IF(COUNTA(r),MIN(IF(TODAY()<r,r)),))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a solution, though maybe there's something more elegant:

```
=IF(ArrayFormula(MIN(IF(E2:Z2<TODAY(),FALSE,E2:Z2)))=0,"",ArrayFormula(MIN(IF(E2:Z2<TODAY(),FALSE,E2:Z2))))
```

basically wrap the whole thing in if (the output of the function = 0), return blank, otherwise, run the function

Comment: Are you using `Excel` or `Google-Sheets`?

Comment: You can actually use `LET()` here. `=LET(a, ArrayFormula(MIN(IF(E2:Z2<TODAY(),FALSE,E2:Z2))), IF(a=0,"",a))`

Comment: I'm using Google Sheets

Answer (score 0):

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(COUNTIF(E2:Z2,">"&TODAY())=0,"",MIN(IF((E2:Z2>=TODAY())*(E2:Z2<>""),E2:Z2,""))))
```

This should work

- `(E2:Z2>=TODAY())*(E2:Z2<>"")`: This checks for dates that are both
  after today's date and non-empty.
- `IF(...,E2:Z2,"")`: This returns the date if the conditions are met;
  otherwise, it returns an empty string.
- `MIN(...)`: This finds the smallest date value in the array, ignoring
  empty strings.
- `IF(COUNTIF(E2:Z2,">"&TODAY())=0,"", ...)`: This checks if there are
  any dates greater than today's date. If not, it returns an empty
  string instead of proceeding with the MIN function.